# What does the operator -i do in `impala-shell -i localhost`

Tags: database, command-line, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

As per impala documentation, you start impala shell using this command

`$ impala-shell -i localhost --quiet`

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_tutorial.html#tut_beginner

Any idea what `-i` does? and why we needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I think I found the answer.

### By default impala-shell connect to localhost. So by only doing

`$ impala-shell`

This is going to go to the default impala host, port 21000

`[localhost:21000] >`

### In case you are you want to manage impala in a cluster or a remote server you should specify a host by using the operator `-i`

such as `impala-shell -i host.yourdomain.com`

`[host.yourdomain.com:21000] >`

#### Or to a different port

such as `impala-shell -i host.yourdomain.com:26000`

`[host.yourdomain.com:26000] >`